# find the value of limit

Tags: calculus

Find the value of
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \frac{1}{k}
$$
I think it become a series with each denominator approach infinity. so the value of the limit is 0. am i true ?

Comment: Not really, because there are infinitely many terms, they don't necessarily add to zero even if all of them tends to zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sum can be written

$$\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{n}} + \frac{1}{1 + \frac{2}{n}} + \cdots + \frac{1}{1 + \frac{n}{n}}\right),$$

which is a sequence of Riemann sums of the function $1/(1 + x)$ over the interval $[0,1]$. So the limit is

$$\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{1 + x} = \log|1 + x|\bigg|_{x = 0}^1 = \log(2) - \log(1) = \log(2).$$

Comment: when you convert Riemann sums to definite integral, why 1/n become dx ?

Comment: @antoniokevin kevin it doesn't, and I didn't convert the sums to the integral. It's the limit of those Riemann sums that gives the integral.

Comment: thank you Kobe for the answer.